# Dynamic routing will not display component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom v6, "react": "^18.2.0", and not able to render a Details component. This is my routing:

```
function Routing() {
  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<List />} />         
        <Route path="details/:id" element={<Details />} />
        <Route path="other" element={<Other />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I am using this to try to access the Details component:

```
<Link to={'details' + `/${props.id}`}/>
```

The details component is as basic as this:

```
import react from 'React'

const Details = () => {
   return (<h1>HELLO</h1>)
}

export default Details;
```

But the  component will not render, and I am getting the warning "No routes matched location "/details/weI4qFO9/UW9v5WFllYhFw==""

It's only dynamic routing that will not render the component. Any idea what I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have these characters `=="` at the end of your url? React router may have problem parsing these.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the router and routes. Where exactly is this link being rendered? Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Oh, I see, there's a `"/"` character in the middle of your id value, i.e. "weI4qFO9 ***/*** UW9v5WFllYhFw==". There's no path to match this. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: Thank you! It was the id causing the issue. This can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the / before details on the router and the link

```
function Routing() {
  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<List />} />         
        <Route path="/details/:id" element={<Details />} />
        <Route path="/other" element={<Other />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

<Link to={`/details/${props.id}`}/>
```

Comment: The root `"/"` is implicit at the router, the `Routes` component can manage relative routes from its parent, i.e. the implicit `"/"`. OP's routing code is fine, the issue is  the detail ids containing invalid characters (*for use in a URL*). Don't believe(?), here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-routing-will-not-display-component-3g1s5x) I used to test OP's code.